shibboleth sp embedded discovery service
Experts, could not get this to working
Not seen IDP selection screen yet..
Shibboleth as SP
Oracle IDCS - idp1
id.me - idp2
EDS configuration steps, inputs appreciated

Exception : Return address not whitelisted

welcome, what is the business related issue or problem? Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.
